# ElasticSearch - maintain original timestamp across versions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have enabled automatic _timestamp on my indexes but every time an index is updated during a _bulk request (or a regular update) the timestamp is also updated. This makes sense.

I want to know if there's a way to keep the original timestamp after an update? So we only ever see the timestamp for version 1 no matter how many times it is updated to a new version.

I have over 4 millions indexes and bulk update in chunks of 1000 so I'd rather not iterate through every single item to compare timestamps.

Any tips?

Comment: In mysql I do this by setting _timestamp=_timestamp - this prevents SQL's automatic function from running.  Not sure if that would work in elasticsearch though

Comment: @Kevin nice idea but unfortunately that's not possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this issue in the future I ended up using a combination of bulk update with script to upsert a date. This only happens when an index is created and left alone during updates. I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution but it works.

```
{ "update": {"_id" : "1"} },
{ "script": "", "upsert" : {"og_index_date" : 20130826}},
{ "update": {"_id" : "1"} },
{ "doc": {"field1" : "one", "field2": "two"}, "doc_as_upsert" : True }
```

Even though you're doubling your writes, it will maintain this date across versions.